# clear property not working on nth-child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

It may seem basic but, `clear:both;` is not working on my `li` tag when i am using `nth-child()` selector.

```
li{
    display: block;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:1px;
    float: left;
}
li:nth-child(1){
    background:#ff0000;
    clear:both;
}
li:nth-child(even){
    background: #0000ff;
}
```

But it work's perfectly fine when used in main `li` tag.

```
<body>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</body>
```

code does not work even when I use `div` instead on `li`.

Comment: That's not all of the HTML is it? It's invalid...

Comment: Actually it is all of the HTML that I wrote as of now. I am gonna add more, but what ever i posted is all base of my idea, if it does not work then i have to know why and figure out something else

Comment: You must wrap `<li>` with either `<ul>` or `<ol>`, otherwise you will get unexpected (and undesirable) results.

Comment: then also it does not work

Comment: Not sure what you mean...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because it is still floating to the left side.

Remove that with `float:none`

```css
li{
    display: block;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:1px;
    float: left;
}
li:nth-child(1){
    background:#ff0000;
    clear:both;
  float:none;
}
li:nth-child(even){
    background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</body>
```

Comment: sorry but I need to float them,it's just I am planning add multiple number of LI tags and need clear only the first one